Change MKR Zero SD SPI Pins
I have been trying to learn more about using the ATSAMD21 MCU with Arduino.  I designed and assembled a bare bones breakout board and have successfully flashed the MKR Zero bootloader and uploaded sketches via an SD card using the SDU library.
It would be nice to be able to change which pins are used for the SD card but every attempt I make is unsuccessful (using the Adafruit guide for adding a new SPI).  The steps I follow are:

Upload a sketch that is compiled using the original variant files.
Change the variant files.
Restart IDE (I've tried rebooting the machine as well).
Compile sketch, copy binary file to SD card.
Upload with SD breakout attached to original SD SPI pins.

At this point I would expect the SD SPI pins to update to PA20, PA21, PA22, PA23 as shown in the modified code below.  However, the sketch fails to upload unless I keep the SD breakout connected to the original SD SPI pins.
MKR Zero Original Variant.h:
// SPI1: Connected to SD
#define PIN_SPI1_MISO (29u)
#define PIN_SPI1_MOSI (26u)
#define PIN_SPI1_SCK  (27u)
#define PIN_SPI1_SS   (28u)
#define PERIPH_SPI1   sercom4
#define PAD_SPI1_TX   SPI_PAD_0_SCK_1
#define PAD_SPI1_RX   SERCOM_RX_PAD_3

MKR Zero Modified Variant.h:
// SPI1: Connected to SD
#define PIN_SPI1_MISO (6u) //PA20
#define PIN_SPI1_MOSI (0u) //PA22
#define PIN_SPI1_SCK  (7u) //PA21
#define PIN_SPI1_SS   (1u) //PA23
#define PERIPH_SPI1   sercom3
#define PAD_SPI1_TX   SPI_PAD_0_SCK_3
#define PAD_SPI1_RX   SERCOM_RX_PAD_2

MKR Zero Original Variant.cpp:
  { PORTA, 12, PIO_SERCOM_ALT, (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // MOSI: SERCOM4/PAD[0]
  { PORTA, 13, PIO_SERCOM_ALT, (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // SCK:  SERCOM4/PAD[1]
  { PORTA, 14, PIO_DIGITAL,    (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // SS:   as GPIO
  { PORTA, 15, PIO_SERCOM_ALT, (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // MISO: SERCOM4/PAD[3]

MKR Zero Modified Variant.cpp:
  { PORTA, 22, PIO_SERCOM,     (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // MOSI: SERCOM3/PAD[0]
  { PORTA, 21, PIO_SERCOM_ALT, (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // SCK:  SERCOM3/PAD[3]
  { PORTA, 23, PIO_DIGITAL,    (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // SS:   as GPIO
  { PORTA, 20, PIO_SERCOM_ALT, (PIN_ATTR_NONE), No_ADC_Channel, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_NONE }, // MISO: SERCOM3/PAD[2]

Am I doing something wrong?  Do the changes have anything to do with the bootloader?  Any help is appreciated.

The SDU library contains binaries of the SDUBoot sketch built for specific boards.
Since the SDUBoot sketch was built for specific board with its default SPI pins and selected CS pin, it is no possible to change the SPI pins or the CS pin in the sketch which uses the SDU library.

Looking through the SDUBoor sketch, I do not see anything indicating which pins are used.  Is there a certain process that can be followed to change the pins?  Maybe change the variant files like I have, open the SDUBoot sketch in the Arduino IDE, compile and do something with the output files?

@SolveEtCoagula07, every board has default SPI pins defined as they are marked on the pinout diagram for the board

Wouldn't build.sh be used to generate the binaries for the SDUBoot sketch?  I made changes and compared the output header file with the header file for the same board on github.  It seemed that this would work but when I tried to compile a new sketch that includes SDU.h, I receive an error "too many initializers for 'unsigned char [16384]".

@SolveEtCoagula07 your bin of SDUBoot is larger than the space reserved for the SDU boot binary (0x4000). do you have debug enabled?

The original mkrzero.h file is 91.4k while the one I generate when running build.sh is 106.5.  Are there parameters I need to add to the command that will reduce the size?  I have not modified anything in the variant files or SDUBoot.ino.
